# How to achieve focus effect as shown in images?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view

I want to know how to get this effect. There is a text header and a RecyclerView / HorizontalGridView. When the focus is not on the RecyclerView / HorizontalGridView, the header text size is small. 
[image]

When any item on RecycleView / HorizontalGridView has focus the header text size increases. I want to create multiple such rows how to handle this? 
[image]

Comment: handle increase/decrease text size with `onTouchListener` on each row

Comment: It's for TV screen